# POST Difference between single frame & request + payload

Tags: http, post, payload

I've noticed that there is two different ways to send POST request:

1. (This one is mostly used by browsers) Single frame HTTP:Request with POST command and all related data (headers & data itself) like it described in RFC
2. (I usually see in in any http libraries for different languages) Two frames:
   First frame is HTTP:Request with POST command and headers (but without data) and second frame HTTP:HTTP Payload which only contains post data.

So what's the difference between this two types of requests? Can second way cause problems in understanding post requests by server?

Answer (score 0):

Framing is handled at the TCP layer, not at the HTTP layer.  If there is a delay between the time the client sends the request headers and sends the request body, the Nagle algorithm can frame them separately.

Another possibility is if the request includes an `Expect: 100-Continue` header, the client will wait for the server to send a `100` reply (or a timeout) before sending the request body. This allows the server to fail/reject the request without having the client waste bandwidth sending data the server would ignore.